# Responsive Cards with images and max-width:100%

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've started learning CSS & Tailwind, and tried building responsive cards that have images inside them. However, Tailwind apparently applies `max-width:100%` and flex-wrap has no effect, but if we override `max-width` it's working again. So my question: is overriding `max-width` a correct solution or I am doing something wrong?

Code in question (Used React only for the sake of not repeating):

```
export default function Cringe() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4">
      {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, num) => (
        <div className="flex-1">
          <img
            className="max-w-none"
            src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/number3/number3_PNG14994.png"
            alt="bag"
          />
          <div>
            <h1>Some title {num}</h1>
            <p>{num !== 1 ? "some text" : "some text".repeat(20)}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with overriding `max-width` of your element. I recently encountered another problem and while wandering on the Internet, I found this conversation here. You might wanna give a glance at it: [Setting default max-width and height for img tag](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/506). This seems to be a pull request to TailwindCSS's repository. However it has been closed.

In conclusion, just do what you said in the question. I think it's fine and not against any conventions.